# RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop using Matplotlib with Django

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, django-templates, html-injections

I am creating a Matplotlib figure to display in a HTML template in my Django application. I send this figure to the HTML by saving it under my static files, and then loading an `img` tag with the saved `.png`.
I do this in my `views.py` after getting a reference to the figure.

```
        # Get analysis visualization chart
        figure = analyser.visualize_tweets(emotions)

        # Save figure in static folder as png
        figure.savefig('static/analysis_figures/figure.png')

        # Inject html with figure path
        response['analysis_figure_path'] = 'analysis_figures/figure.png'

return render(request, 'landing_page/index.html', response)
```

My HTML is something like this:

```
<img src={% static analysis_figure %} alt="">
```

However, this caused the `RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop` to happen when the function in my `views.py` is called a second time (if it's called once everything works properly).
To prevent this error, I moved saving the Matplotlib figure to `main()` as to run in the main thread and then call it in my original function. This fixed the error, but prevents my HTML from reloading so every time the user submits a query the new figure is displayed over the previous one without the previous one being removed.
Any ideas on any of the problems ?

Answer (score 10):

I think this post explains what to do:
[How to clean images in Python / Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147300/how-to-clean-images-in-python-django)

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

As explained here: https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#matplotlib-in-a-web-application-server

To prevent that the new figure is displayed over the previous one use:
`plt.close() / figure.close()`

Comment: Second link does not work, here is an [updated link](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/web_application_server_sgskip.html).

Answer (score -1):

I am using Matplotlib package, it is generating a graph in runtime that i changing from Matplotlib image object into normal PNG Image, then i inserted in my django web Application. Here, Every time the Graph Image changing frequently as my website so i converted into binary image object and runtime locally stored as image ! then i getting location address from URI.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.bar(x, y, tick_label = tick_label, 
width = 0.8, color = ['red','yellow', 'green']) 
    

plt.xlabel('x - axis') 

plt.ylabel('y - axis') 

plt.title('My bar chart!') 

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
    
fig=plt.gcf()
plt.close()

`enter code here`# convert graph
buf=io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(buf,format='png')        
buf.seek(0)
string =base64.b64encode(buf.read())

uri=urllib.parse.quote(string)

context={'imgdata':uri}
```

Comment: Hi Ammy, thank you for your answer. Could you maybe add some comments on what your code does?

Comment: Yes, I am using Matplotlib package, it is generating a graph in runtime that i changing from Matplotlib image object into normal PNG Image, then i inserted in my django web Application. Here, Every time the Graph Image changing frequently as my website so i converted into binary image object and runtime locally stored as image ! then i getting location address from URI. These is I done because graph result is changing we have to update that's why !!

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, I just asked, because I was reviewing your answer and I thought an explanation might be usefull. Btw. I didn't downvote your answer.