# Python plot image save error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, django-rest-framework

I am new to Python. I have written Web service using Django to save image in server. I am trying to save plot as image using below code and it works fine for 3 times, after that Python throws error. How to fix this issue ?

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x000000000FE40048>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\dev\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3504, in __del__
    self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Exception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x0000000010996438>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\dev\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3504, in __del__
    self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Exception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x0000000010B8BF98>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\dev\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3504, in __del__
    self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread


**PYTHON CODE**  
fileName = id_generator()+".png"
filePath = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+"/"+fileName
fig.savefig(filePath, dpi=fig.dpi)
plt.close(fig) 
Response(fileName, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

Package             Version
------------------- ---------
cassandra-driver    3.14.0
certifi             2018.4.16
cycler              0.10.0
Django              2.0.5
djangorestframework 3.8.2
kiwisolver          1.0.1
matplotlib          2.2.2
numpy               1.14.4
pandas              0.23.0
pip                 10.0.1
pyparsing           2.2.0
python-dateutil     2.7.3
pytz                2018.4
scikit-learn        0.19.1
scipy               1.1.0
setuptools          39.2.0
six                 1.11.0
wheel               0.31.1
wincertstore        0.2
```

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem in a different situation. As mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29172195/2620444), `matplotlib.use('Agg')` should be added.  This should solve your problem.