# Find first instance of package import in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, python-import

I need to set the backend for matplotlib in order to apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147300/how-to-clean-images-in-python-django) for addressing issues with non-thread-safe code in Tkinter and using the Tk backend in matplotlib. According to the post I need to do

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

but setting the backend must be done **before** any imports of pyplot. I thought I found the first import, but I keep getting this warning:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:1352: UserWarning:  This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect because the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot, or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.
```

My codebase is somewhat large and complex, so it's becoming a pain for me to try to track down where the very first import of pyplot is. Is there a way to test this programmatically, or is there a debug tool I can use to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Try `matplotlib.use('Agg',warn=False,force=True)`. This might be duplicate of [How to switch backends in matplotlib / Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285193/how-to-switch-backends-in-matplotlib-python)