# kochat in use RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, processing, chatbot

kochat is a Korean chatbot, and I ran into a problem while practicing it.
github imformation : https://github.com/hyunwoongko/kochat

### It is environment setting

1. python3.8
2. pip install kochat
3. JPype is reinstalled ues JPype1-1.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl <-download
4. pytorch is same ver with cuda 11.1

### start code

```
### from kochat.proc import DistanceClassifier ###
from kochat.data import Dataset
from kochat.proc import GensimEmbedder, DistanceClassifier
from kochat.model import intent, embed
from kochat.loss import CenterLoss


dataset = Dataset(ood=True)

emb = GensimEmbedder(model=embed.Word2Vec())

# 프로세서 생성
clf = DistanceClassifier(
    model=intent.CNN(dataset.intent_dict),
    loss=CenterLoss(dataset.intent_dict)
)

# 되도록이면 DistanceClassifier는 Margin 기반의 Loss 함수를 이용해주세요
# 현재는 CenterLoss, COCOLoss, Cosface, GausianMixture 등의
# 거리기반 Metric Learning 전용 Loss함수를 지원합니다.


# 모델 학습
clf.fit(dataset.load_intent(emb))

# 모델 추론 (인텐트 분류)
clf.predict(dataset.load_predict("오늘 서울 날씨 어떨까", emb))
```

#### error message

```
C:\projectkyc\kochat3.8\Scripts\python.exe "C:/projectkyc/kochat3.8/test3.8/!from kochat.proc import DistanceClassifier.py"`enter code here`
Exception ignored in: <function Image.__del__ at 0x000001E7E1566D30>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4014, in __del__
Exception ignored in: <function Variable.__del__ at 0x000001E7E154B430>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 351, in __del__
    if self._tk.getboolean(self._tk.call("info", "exists", self._name)):
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Exception ignored in: <function Image.__del__ at 0x000001E7E1566D30>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4014, in __del__
    self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (os_windows_x86.cpp:144), pid=11208, tid=0x00000000000037f4
#  guarantee(result == EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION) failed: Unexpected result from topLevelExceptionFilter
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_281-b09) (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.281-b09 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\projectkyc\kochat3.8\test3.8\hs_err_pid11208.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Exception ignored in: <function Image.__del__ at 0x000001E7E1566D30>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4014, in __del__
    self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**If I haven't posted it or if I have the information I need, I will add it immediately upon confirmation if requested.**

Answer (score 1):

This is such an annoying issue and to me setting `matplotlib.use('Agg')` does not cut it. I dont want to comprise on this.

The only thing that seems to do it somewhat consistently is having to close the figure before creating a new plot via `plt.close()`. This is annoying and if i forget it does this.

Answer (score 0):

this error

[Matplotlib - Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147300/matplotlib-tcl-asyncdelete-async-handler-deleted-by-the-wrong-thread)

same Question But did not know where to apply

The places to apply are kochat\utils\visualizer.py and kochat\proc\utils\visualizer.py
to be. In the

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

part of these two places,

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

The problem is solved.